# Error in target function in multiprocessing issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I run the code below:

```
import multiprocessing

sum1 = 0

def list_append_1(out_list):
    global sum1
    for i in out_list:
        sum1 += i
    return sum1

lista_1 = [i for i in xrange(500)]
process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append_1, args=lista_1)
jobs = []
jobs.append(process_1)
for j in jobs:
     j.start()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: list_append_1() takes exactly 1 argument (500 given)
```

Although I pass only 1 argument to `list_append_1()` function. What is wrong?

Comment: try `args=(lista_1,)`

Comment: OK, isn't it a bug in python?

Comment: no, it is a bug in your code; otherwise how can `Process` call a function with more than one argument;

Comment: if only one argument is passed, then it should understand that only one argument is passed. Above I pass only 1 argument (a list which has 500 items). It thinks I passed 500 arguments. It is a bug.

Comment: yes, it is a bug in your code

Comment: It is a bug in python.

Comment: Which seems more likely: 1. despite the millions of person-hours that have gone into writing, testing and using Python all over the world for years, there is a bug in a standard library module only you could be smart enough to spot; or 2. your code is wrong? `args` expects a single sequence object, where each item in the sequence is a separate argument. If you have a sequence with multiple items that should be only one argument (your list), you must put that inside a second sequence (the tuple suggested by @behzad.nouri). This is common wherever `args` and `kwargs` are used.

Comment: the same thing happens when I put lista_1 in paranthesis: args=(lista_1), what I'm trying to say: the comma (,)should not be necessary here.

Comment: This is a common mistake (see e.g. [this Python wiki article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)): except for empty tuples, the syntax is the **comma**, not the parentheses.

Comment: Maybe someone has to suggest that the necessity of comma is redundant in this case, and in next release of python they will remove this necessity.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "anything wrong with your code must be a bug in Python" when have I claimed that???

Comment: If you want to engage with the development community and suggest language changes, do so through the [PEP system](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/). Such a significant change to the fundamental syntax would have to have an exceptionally good reasoning, though, as it would potentially mean breaking a great deal of existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Argument should be passed this way:

```
process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append_1, args=(lista_1,))
```